# Visual Studio Code- Python- Not resolving multiple input statements

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

VScode is not resolving separate lines of input statements. It does resolve one input statement, but doesn't work on separate lines

Single input statement:

```
a = input("a: ")

>>> a = input("a: ")
a:
```

Multiple input statements:

```
a = input("a: ")
b = input("b: ")

>>> a = input("a: ")
a: b = input("b: ")
>>>
```

I have enabled code runner, yet that doesn't resolve this issue.

Comment: try restarting vs code and clearing cache

Comment: first get it working without code-runner

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! It did resolve the issue. I realized that this happens when I selectively run a statement using 'Shift+Enter'. So once I ran a specific statement, I cleared the cache and killed the terminal. Not sure if this is the right method, but yes it did resolve the issue.